# Switch boot loader

Tags: ssd

I already have Ubuntu 20.02 installed on my 500GB HDD and everything seem to be working fine.
However, lately I bought a new SSD and would like to switch to boot the Ubuntu 20.04 OS from the SSD instead of the HDD. I tried to reinstall the Ubuntu 20.02 OS to the new SSD but during the installation, the new SSD was not detected. What is the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a USB and clone the HDD to SSD with dd
Change the UUID of the new filesystem. I missed that one at first, which caused funny results as grub and other software got confused
Update the fstab on the new filesystem. I used the genfstab script from the Arch USB for that
Re-generate initramfs, reinstall and reconfigure grub
Move SSD to the top in boot priority, done

Comment: Sorry....I just started to use Ubuntu OS and not familiar with the Linux environment yet. Can you provide a step by step procedure to solve this problem for me? Appreciate your help on this

Comment: How would one clone to a SSD which is not detected?

Comment: Sorry....I double check in Disk utility. My 80GB SSD was detected but when I tried to mount it, it gave me an error saying "error mounting filesystem"